# Iterating Through Many to Many Model

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I have a model like so:

```
`class task(models.Model):

 name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

 notes = models.TextField()

 created = models.DateTimeField()

 created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)

 subtask = models.ManyToManyField('self')
```

`
I'm having trouble writing out the view for it, essentially

```
<li>task #1</li>
  <li>subtask#1.1</li>
  <li>subtask#1.2</li>
<li>task #2</li>
  <li>subtask#2.1</li>
  <li>subtask#2.2</li>
  .
  .
.
.
```

I tried creating a for loop to iterate through them using but it doesn't show up nested like how I would want it

```
{% for task in items %}
 <li>{{ task.name }}</li>
{% for subtask in task %}
  <li>{{ subtask.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an HTML issue rather than with your django code

```
{% for task in items %}
 <li>{{ task.name }}
   <ul>

    {% for subtask in task.subtask.all %}
      <li>{{ subtask.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
 </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It says task object is not iterable. So I tried changing the code to   {% for subtask in task.all %} but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Sorry never, mind, I spotted another error in your template and fixed it. Please see update

Comment: Is there a way to iterate through them all without defining a for loop for each one. Like if I wanted 5 levels, I don't want to type 5 for loops.

Comment: glad it works. Sorry I don't quite understand that comment

Comment: If I had a subsubtask and a subsubsubtask. How would I iterate through them without going {% for subsubtask %} {% for subsubsubtask %}

Comment: shoot aparrently I can only post once 90 minutes